# convert text to date datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Maturity column is of `date` datatype.

```
select TO_char(maturity,'YYYY-MM') || '-15' from tablename
```

The above query returns me the column value with `text` datatype. But how can i return the column value as `date` datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast to date using ::date. ie:

```
select (TO_char(maturity,'YYYY-MM') || '-15')::date from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using date arithmetic:

```
select maturity + (15 - extract(day from maturity)) * interval '1 day'
```

In general, I prefer not to convert to strings to do things that can be handled by date/time functions.